# Get_the_author doesn't return author name

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to show meta contents on single page. But `get_the_author()` is not showing. The result of the below code is

> Written by on July 14, 2015

and it is supposed to show

> Written by **admin** on July 14, 2015

Anyone knows what I am missing? Here is the code:

```
function mano_posted_on() {
    $time_string = '<time class="entry-date published" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time>';
    if (get_the_time('U') !== get_the_modified_time('U')) {
        $time_string.= '<time class="updated" datetime="%3$s">%4$s</time>';
    }

    $time_string = sprintf(
            $time_string,
            esc_attr(get_the_date('c')),
            esc_html(get_the_date()),
            esc_attr(get_the_modified_date('c')),
            esc_html(get_the_modified_date())
    );

    printf(
            __('<span class="byline">Written by %1$s</span><span class="posted-on">on %2$s</span>', 'mano'),
            sprintf(
                '<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="%1$s">%2$s</a></span>',
                esc_url(get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID'))),
                esc_html(get_the_author())
            ),
            sprintf(
                '<a href="%1$s" rel="bookmark">%2$s</a>',
                esc_url(get_permalink()),
                $time_string
            )
        );
}
```

Comment: What is displayed if you `var_dump(get_the_author())`?

Comment: Or is there any `display: none` CSS attribute active, e.g. on `.author` or `.vcard`?

Comment: Had the same issue.  It only works inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

> To return to PHP rather than displaying, use get_the_author().
>   https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author

So try changing `get_the_author()` to `the_author()`.

Comment: Close miss: `get_the_author()` is used within `printf()`, so output is already given.

Comment: Actually, `get_the_author()` is included in a `printf` statement, so `get_the_author()` s is the proper way to do it and `the_author()` isn't!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
echo get_the_author($post->author_id);
```

Make $post as global.

so it will look like on top of file :

```
global $post;
```